# Swift 2 (iOS 9) - navigation bar error when using one ViewController for both create and update

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I'm using one ViewController that can perform both create new data and update data.

The data is getting passed to this destination ViewController but I get an error on setting the navigation bar inside `if data != nil`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if data != nil {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Edit ...";
    } else {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "New ...";
    }

    ...

}
```

It says `Thread 1: EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=...)`

and the following in the console.

```
2016-03-15 01:25:16.526 Project[2508:130565] <UIView: 0x7fccfd814c70; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fccfd814de0>>'s window is not equal to <Project.CreateRecipeVC: 0x7fccfb67b5d0>'s view's window!
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I think the navigation bar is confused about its window view or something.
In the simulator, navigation bar is not getting displayed on update page.

How can I make the navigation bar to work for both create and update?

Comment: Did you check your navigationController is not nil? If not nil you should check that topItem not nil.

Comment: I'm not sure why navigationController would be nil and not showing on update screen but show on create screen.

Comment: Do you use storyboards or creating everything programatically?

Comment: I do both..I needed to set title this way because storyboard didn't show the title

Comment: Check the answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should'n use `if data != nil` 
The solution is that you use `if let` for better practises.

Something like this will fix the found nil error

```
if let result = data {

} else {

}
```

The same goes for `UINavigationController`, you should test if it's nil.

After that, check your connections. If all outlets and actions are firmly connected.

Comment: UINavigationController seems to be nil...how do I fix this?

Comment: You mean, did I add UINavigationControllerDelegate as the viewcontroller class type? if that's so, yes I did. This view controller is used for create new data screen and shows navigation bar.

Comment: @SeongLee Did you create UINavigationController programatically or within Storyboard? Because it needs to be in the the View Stack, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Try to check if it's nil in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: doing this? if UINavigationController == nil {
            print("it's nil")
        }
Xcode complains that UINavigationController can never be nil

Comment: No, not that.. You have to check if your instance of that class is nil.. 
Solution is one of these things:
1) you access the UINavigationController by self.navigationController, not by UINavigationController because you want to check for object, not for class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106239/discussion-between-seong-lee-and-dragos-strugar).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out in chat. Because you have pointed out the absence of navigation element in my storyboard, I was able to track down the error. About the data transfer issue between segue that I mentioned in the chat, I solved it by ctrl + drag from viewcontroller to viewcontroller rather than from a button or a cell to viewcontroller.

Comment: @SeongLee Cool! Glad to hear that you've made it!